# flujo para convertir valores None a su valor previo numérico

Tags: python, array

Estoy atascada con este ejercicio.

```
def function(x):
    
assert(function([1, None, 2, 3, None, None, 5, None])) == [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
assert(function([None, 2, 3])) == [None, 2 ,3]
assert(function([])) == []
assert(function([None])) == [None]
assert(function([None, None, None])) == [None, None, None]
```

No sé cómo plantear el flujo para que si hay un valor antes de None, None adquiera ese valor y si no hay ningún valor antes de None, que siga siendo None.
Independientemente de que le dé un assert con 8 valores, con 2 o ninguno.

CÓDIGO YA CORREGIDO GRACIAS A LA AYUDA DE UN USUARIO DE STACK OVER FLOW

```
def function(x):
    """Given an array containing None values fill in the None values
    with most recent non None value in the array"""

    element_1 = None
    output = []
    for valor in x:
        if valor is None:
            output.append(element_1)
        else:
            output.append(valor)

        element_1 = output[-1]

    print(output)

    return output
```

Comment: `int()` es una función que requiere un parámetro, así: `int("45")` devuelve el valor entero (45) del string ("45"). Compara `value == int()` es un error de sintaxis y lógico.

Comment: La función recibe `x, y` como parámetros, pero de inmediato los reemplaza por " ". No tiene sentido.

Comment: `None` es una palabra reservada; `"None"` es un string. Dos cosas completamente distintas.

Comment: gracias, voy añadiendo esas correcciones... ¿cuál sería el planteamiento entonces?

Comment: Deberias partir por el tutorial de Python, para conocer los elementos básicos del lenguaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
def proc(lista):
    prev = None
    salida = []
    for valor in lista:
        if valor is None:
            salida.append(prev)
        else:
            salida.append(valor)
        prev = salida[-1]
    return salida
```

En cada iteración examinamos un elemento de la lista. Si es `None`, usamos el último valor encontrado, que almacenamos en `prev`. En caso contrario, guardamos el elemento en la nueva lista.

En ambos casos, el último elemento de la nueva lista es usado como `prev`

#### Demo

```
def proc(lista):
    prev = None
    salida = []
    for valor in lista:
        if valor is None:
            salida.append(prev)
        else:
            salida.append(valor)
        prev = salida[-1]
    return salida

tests = [
[1, None, 2, 3, None, None, 5, None],
[None, 2, 3],
[],
[None],
[None, None, None]
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, proc(test))
```

produce:

```
[1, None, 2, 3, None, None, 5, None] [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5]
[None, 2, 3] [None, 2, 3]
[] []
[None] [None]
[None, None, None] [None, None, None]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y tu código. 
La aclaración me ha ayudado a entender el flujo.
Gracias, gracias, gracias